# How do i remove the commas and command?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

When the message from this command gets sent, it has commas between all the words in the reason, and it also shows the command used. How do I remove the command and change the commas to spaces?

```js
  if (message.content.toLowerCase().startsWith(prefix + `testesty`)){

    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(' ');
    if (!args.length) {
        return message.channel.send(`You didn't provide a reason, ${message.author}!`);
    }

    message.channel.send("Report successfully sent");
    client.channels.get('579573817232588823').send(userVar + `need's assistance in Site-15\nReason - ${args} `)
    }
```

Comment: To remove the command you can again use slice on the args just like you did for the prefix. `args.slice(1)` would remove the first word. To join them back together use `args.join(" ")`.

Answer (score 1):

Solution:

```
...send(userVar + `need's assistance in Site-15\nReason - ${args.join(' ')} `)
```

Explanation:

Since `args` is derived from `split`, it is an array of strings.

When later you call `send`, you convert `args` to a string by using it in a string template. When an array is implicitly cast to a string, its elements are individually cast to a string and then joint by commas; e.g.

```js
console.log(`${['a', 3, {}]}`);
```

Since you desire joining by spaces, simply explicitly invoke `join`, a native function on arrays.